# Do creatures that are hit with poison attacks (or take poison damage) become Poisoned?

Tags: dnd-5e, poison

> Appendix: POISONED: 
>   A poisoned creature has disadvantage on attack rolls and ability checks.

Would this condition ever be applied to a creature that's stung by giant scorpion's tail-sting attack, or bitten by a poisonous snake (both found in the Monster Manual), or shot with a poisoned arrow? I can see several instances where poison **damage** is applied to a creature, but very few where the poisoned **condition** is applied (so far just the magical poison dagger).

Even poison you can purchase only inflicts poison damage and makes no mention of applying the poisoned condition. There seem to be a great many anti-poison measures but little to no poisoning methods.

Comment: Related [Is a green dragon's breath weapon "poison" for the purposes of "advantage on saves against poison"](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/63587/is-a-green-dragons-breath-weapon-poison-for-the-purposes-of-advantage-on-sav)

Comment: In part it's because of the word poison being considered interchangeable with venom. If it's a venom, then it's produced by the creature in a gland and used as an attack or defense mechanism. Venoms are delivered through an attacking apparatus, such as a scorpions sting, a snakes bite, or a bees stinger. Poisons are contracted through non-direct means, and are debilitating or lethal. A dart frog is poisonous. Nightshade is poisonous. So if a creature delivers it, it really should be labelled as a venom, and thus damaging. If it's not an attack mechanism, it would be a poison, mainly plants.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, if these attacks were meant to inflict the poisoned condition they would specify. For example, the Sprite has an attack that does this:

> ***Shortbow.***
>   Ranged Weapon Attack:
>   +6 to hit, range 40/160
>   ft., one target.
>   Hit:
>   1 piercing damage, and the target must
>   succeed on a DC 10 Constitution saving throw or become
>   poisoned for 1 minute. If its saving throw result is 5 or lower,
>   the poisoned target falls unconscious for the same duration,
>   or until it takes damage or another creature takes an action to
>   shake it awake.

The Giant Scorpion and the Poisonous Snake don't say anything about the poisoned condition, so they don't inflict it.

Comment: You could also cite the Wizard Cantrip _Poison Spray_, which deals Poison damage **and** grants the Poisoned condition.

Comment: Poison Spray doesn't inflict the Poisoned condition, only poison damage, according to the PHB. You may have been thinking of the first-level spell Ray of Sickness, which only inflicts the condition for a single turn.

Comment: Note that the poisoned condition is one of the stronger conditions to inflict on a creature, so having every instance of poison damage trigger it would be very unbalanced.