# Vrock's spore ability inflict both the "poisoned" condition and poison damage, or just poison damage?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, conditions

Does the [Vrock](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/vrock)'s spore ability inflict both the "poisoned" condition and poison damage, or just poison damage? The wording seems unclear.

Comment: @Cœur Those who can’t answer without a quote don’t have the material expertise and *shouldn’t* be answering.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### The target is poisoned

> Each creature in that area must succeed on a DC 14 Constitution saving throw or become poisoned. While poisoned in this way, a target takes 5 (1d10) poison damage at the start of each of its turns.

The target is poisoned *and* suffers additional effects as long as they remain poisoned. A similar wording exists for many spells that inflict the Charmed condition and some additional effect, for example Dominate Person.

Comment: This is, of course, so that creatures immune to the poisoned condition are immune to this as well.

Comment: @RobRose: And also, "A poisoned creature has disadvantage on attack rolls and ability checks." https://open5e.com/gameplay-mechanics/conditions.html#poisoned.  See also [Do creatures that are hit with poison attacks (or take poison damage) become Poisoned?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/64318).  I'm trying to figure out whether poisons that inflict damage over time or have other special side effects still impose disadvantage, but from the wording it would seem so.  If being immune to the Poisoned condition works here, then the RAW effects of that condition are also relevant.