# Are creatures with the immune to poisoned condition immune to poison damage?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, conditions, immunities, poison

For example Flesh Golem is immune to the poisoned condition... would that make them immune to poison damage?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

## No, but flesh golems are also immune to poison damage

The poisoned condition and the poison damage type have no mechanical link beyond the fact that they are both *poison* derived.  This is relevant for features like the Monk's Purity of Body which grants "immunity to [...] poison".  Which is to say something caring about or affecting one does not automatically affect the other. Obviously they tend to show up together, but not always.
Some notable exceptions:

- Circle of Spores Druids are [immune to the condition, but not the damage type](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/144891/52137).
- [Astral Dreadnoughts](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/astral-dreadnought) similarly have immunity to the condition, but not even resistance to the damage type. Conversely, [bone nagas](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/bone-naga) have immunity to the damage type, but not the condition.
- There are creatures like sprites that [inflict the condition, but not the damage type](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/64319/52137) and creatures (eg. Giant Scorpion) which deal poison damage, but do not inflict the condition.

So the [flesh golem](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/flesh-golem)'s poisoned condition immunity does not automatically give it immunity to poison damage, however listed among its damage immunities (the entry above condition immunities ) is poison damage, so it is also immune to the damage type.