# What does "immune to poison" mean in Nature's Ward?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, druid, poison

Circle of the Land druids get the Nature's Ward feature:

> When you reach 10th level, you can't be charmed or frightened by
>   elementals or fey, and you are immune to poison and disease. (PHB 69)

My question is specifically about the **"immune to poison"** part. Does it make you immune to poison damage? To the poisoned condition? Both?

Treating it as natural english, my hunch would be the last, but is there official clarification? (I do not consider reveal of designer intent to be official, but I would like to hear it if no proper source is available.)

Comment: When you say "official clarification", are you looking for a designer intent answer or an answer pulled from Sage Advice, or is it just synedoche for rules support?

Comment: Highly related: "[Is a green dragon's breath weapon “poison” for the purposes of “advantage on saves against poison”](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/63587)"

Comment: @Xirema I would prefer information that is not just intent, but an official ruling (eg. published errata), but if such is not available, other sources are welcome.

Comment: Would you want an answer from the Sage Advice Compendium (not just the Sage Advice twitter)?

Comment: @Medix2 Wherever you can find it. I couldn't. If it does not exist, this question is to stand here as a reminder of that absence...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Following the precedent set forth by the Sage Advice Compendium, "immunity to poison" includes both the Poisoned condition and the poison damage type

The [Sage Advice Compendium](https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf) has two instances of explaining what "poison" means:

> Q. Does a monk’s Purity of Body feature grant immunity to poison damage, the poisoned condition, or both?
>
> A. That feature grants immunity to both...
>
> Q. Does the *heroes’ feast* spell grant immunity to poison damage or just the poison condition?
>
> A.  The *heroes’ feast* spell grants immunity to poison in any form—damage and the condition.

We note that both of these features use the same wording as Nature's Ward:

> At 10th level, your mastery of the ki flowing through you makes you **immune to disease and poison.**
>
> [...] The creature is cured of all diseases and poison, becomes **immune to poison**...
>
> When you reach 10th level, you can't be charmed or frightened by elementals or fey, and you are **immune to poison** and disease.

Thus there is no reason to believe that Nature's Ward would work any differently. "Immunity to poison" means you are immune to both the Poisoned condition and poison-type damage.

Comment: Heroes' feast is a great spell to use before fighting a Green Dragon.

Comment: Love this, but my hunch isy ou can support this through the existing rules, too.

Comment: @NautArch I tried to do that, but couldn't find much of anything. It would be up to a GM to determine whether the natural English word "poison" includes the condition and damage type, as the word "poison" is never defined explicitly by the rules