# Does resistance to a damage type prevent similarly named conditions from applying?

Tags: dnd-5e, conditions, damage-resistance

Creatures with resistances take half the damage from an attack of the type it is resistant to. But what happens if a condition is applied? For example, if someone with poison resistance gets poisoned condition, without any actual damage.

Comment: Related link on the opposite question: [Are creatures with the immune to poison condition immune to poison damage?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/165597/are-creatures-with-the-immune-to-poisoned-condition-immune-to-poison-damage) as well as one on conditions vs damage in [What does immune to poison mean in Nature's Ward?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/156316/what-does-immune-to-poison-mean-in-natures-ward)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Damage resistance does not interact with status conditions.

The [rules for damage resistance](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#DamageResistanceandVulnerability) state:

> If a creature or an object has resistance to a damage type, damage of that type is halved against it. If a creature or an object has vulnerability to a damage type, damage of that type is doubled against it.

No mention of status effects. Status effect immunity is an entirely separate feature from damage resistance and immunity.

Poison can be especially confusing, as resistance to poison damage does not *a priori* offer immunity or advantage against the poison condition, but features which offer one often also offer the other.

Comment: It's worth mentioning, that especially with poison, often both advantage on saving throws against poison, and resistance to poison damage, are given by same feature (at least some dwarf racial feature, and some tiefling feat) as separate benefits.

Comment: Examples: The Assassin has Poison resistance but no immunity to the poisoned condition. This seems to be the standard situation for most most monsters in fact (just by filtering in DnDBeyond). Only a few monsters have both poison resistance and immunity to the poisoned condition such as the Karrnathi Undead Soldier (from Eberron)

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing as "similarly named conditions" comparing with damage types.

Here's the list of conditions (per PHB p.290):

- Blinded
- Charmed
- Deafened
- Frightened
- Grappled
- Incapacitated
- Invisible
- Paralyzed
- Petrified
- Poisoned
- Prone
- Restrained
- Stunned
- Unconscious

And here's the list of all damage types:

- Acid
- Bludgeoning
- Cold
- Fire
- Force
- Lightning
- Necrotic
- Piercing
- Poison
- Psychic
- Radiant
- Slashing
- Thunder

It seems that **Poison** is the only type of damage with a condition of the same name. Having the same name is probably a coincidence, not a design.

By default, neither resistance nor immunity to **Poison** damage affects **Poisoned** condition in any way. However, they are often mentioned together:

> #### Quasit
>
> **Damage Immunities** poison
> **Condition Immunities** poisoned

> #### Aura of purity
>
> Each nonhostile creature in the aura (including you) can't become diseased, has **resistance to poison damage**, and has advantage on saving throws against effects that cause any of the following conditions: blinded, charmed, deafened, frightened, paralyzed, **poisoned**, and stunned.

Thus, if poison resistance is accompanied by the poisoned condition immunity, it is said explicitly. There is no secret rule "Resistance to poison damage gives you immunity to poisoned condition":

> Beware of claims that a rule does something mentioned nowhere in that rule or elsewhere in the core books. There aren't secret rules. ([source](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/857269923134939136))

Comment: @KorvinStarmast It was general before the edit anyway. Asking about "a status" and "matching resistance" while only citing poison as an "example"